# convergence of series and sum and series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Say $\sum a_n+b_n$ converges then will it automatically mean $\sum a_n$ converges as well as $\sum b_n$, too?

If $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ both converge will it be the case that $\sum a_n-b_n$ converge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your second question is "yes". You should be able to prove it from the definition.

For the first, what if all $a_n = 1$ and all $b_n = -1$?

**Edit** in response to comment.

If the terms are all  nonnegative then each series converges since the increasing sequence of partial sums of each is bounded by the sum of the sums.

Comment: Ah good shout, what if $a_n$ and $b_n$ both greater than or equal to 0 then will it hold?